# mpmath implementation details for basic operations

Tags: floating-point, mpmath

I need to implement arbitrary precision floating point routines in OpenCL and I'd like to be able to compare results with mpmath.

For basic operations +,-,*,/ and basic functions exp, log, sqrt etc: does it follow eg IEEE 754 ? And if not is there any other convention/standard/reference that is followed ?

Comment: Have you consulted the [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/) (1) documentation (2) source code?

Comment: I couldn't find something in the documentation. I haven't looked at the source code, it's a number of operations and it would be hard to pin down the answer unless it's explicitly mentioned ...